# Paperclip outputs url instead of image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

In my show view:`<dd><%= @truck_fleet.avatar.url(:medium) %></dd>`

Get the output: `/system/truck_fleets/avatars/000/000/001/medium/logo.thumbnail.png?1354107497`

Def, I would like to display avatar instead for URL :)

Anyone has encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tell rails it is an image:

```
<%= image_tag @truck_fleet.avatar.url(:medium) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is wrap the URL in an `<img>` tag under the `src` attribute like this:

```
<img src="<%= @truck_fleet.avatar.url(:medium) %>"/>
```